# Replace String no MySql

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo uma query em uma tabela. O campo `filiais` retorna o seguinte valor

```
["005","001"]
```

Queria diretamente na query transformar essa string(varchar) em:

```
['005','001']
```

Com as aspas simples

**Minha query**

```
SELECT * FROM bancos WHERE ativo=1
```

Comment: `['005','001']` já *é* o valor cru retornado pela query, certo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a função `REPLACE` do MySql:

```
SELECT REPLACE(filiais, "\"", "\'") FROM bancos WHERE ativo = 1
```

O primeiro parâmetro é a coluna em que será executada a função, o segundo é o caracter antigo e o terceiro o caracter novo.

Comment: Isso mesmo!! vlw!!